# Updating JSONB object using another table

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I am trying to update a JSONB field in one table with data from another table. For example,

```
update ms
set data = data || '{"COMMERCIAL": 3.4, "PCT" : medi_percent}'
from mix
where mix.id = mss.data_id
and data_id = 6000
and set_id = 20
```

This is giving me the following error -

```
Invalid input syntax for type json
DETAIL:  Token "medi_percent" is invalid.
```

When I change `medi_percent` to a number, I don't get this error.

Answer (score 0):

`{"COMMERCIAL": 3.4, "PCT" : medi_percent}` is not a valid JSON text. Notice there is no string interpolation happening here. You might be looking for

```
json_build_object('COMMERCIAL', 3.4, 'PCT', medi_percent)
```

instead where `medi_percent` is now an expression (that will presumably refer to your `mix` column).